# Error when extending module-ui base js file magento 2

Tags: magento

I am trying to extend `module-ui/base/web/js/form/element/select.js`

I have created a module, added `requirejs-config.js` and copied `select.js` by creating same file path as it in vendor.

After setup:upgrade and setup:static-content:deploy, I get error saying

> "Uncaught Error: Script error for:
>   Thelist_Customjs/js/form/element/abstract"

My requirejs-config.js file code is as follows

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select':'Thelist_Customjs/js/form/element/select'
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also copy the file from

```
vendor\magento\module-ui\view\base\web\js\form\element\abstract.js
```

to

```
Thelist_Customjs/js/form/element/abstract.js
```

Becasue in `select.js` that file is used.

Comment: hi @dhiren, can you please share way that how it can be achieved in custom module level.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not working for me  @Dhiren. Can you tell me what's wrong ?

Comment: @Vivek What error you are facing? Do you check consol or error log?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya, Not getting any error but generated file in pub is same as vendor file not apeearing my change. I'm trying to override /vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/form/element/file-uploader.js

Comment: Do you have any idea ? How can I achieve this ? Stuck with this since last 3 hours. :(

Comment: Verify that you follow all the steps, and run caching, deploy command.